# Logic to perform addition in array based on user loggin in

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
// array of moderator code
Array
(
    [0] => M1
    [1] => M2
    [2] => M3
    [3] => M1
)

// array of commission amount and status based on the above array
Array
(
    [10] => Paid
    [20] => Due
    [30] => Cancelled
    [40] => Paid
)
```

If any of the moderator logs in, he should see only his commission details and not of others. For example, if M1 logs in, he should see like this in his my account:

```
OrderCode    PaidAmount    CancelledAmount    DueAmount    Action
    1      50.00 (40 + 10)     0.00             0.00        View
```

And similarly for other moderators also.

How do I achieve this ?

**P.S.**: The above arrays are just an example I am trying to understand in order to build my application. In reality, the order will contain any x number of moderators and it's corresponding commission amount and status and are going to be retrieved from the database.

Comment: I an unable to see any kind of link in your both array will you please explain your post in more detail?

Comment: The first array is of the user. The second array is of the commission amount and commission payment status for the user..

Comment: is the indexes are the commision ammount ?

Comment: Yep.. They are the commission amount for the respective moderators..

Comment: But if two moderators have the same commision amount then it will be overwritten how will you handle that?

Comment: That's where the addition comes.. I need the logic for that only..

Comment: I am not getting your concept I will tell you what i exactly got from your question.  First there are the users called moderators and every moderator have his commision amt and the status of that commision amount

Comment: Yes.. Right.. Exactly..

Comment: and every moderator has access to only his commision amount and status

Comment: yeah.. you are absolutely right..

Comment: then if m1 has the 10  comission and m2 also has the 10 commision then m1 entry will be deleted.

Comment: It won't be deleted.. M1 will see ony his commission amount and status..

Comment: if i m right then you are going to do it using the database ?

Comment: Yes Sir.. But at the moment, I need to create the logic in order to achieve what I want and then I'll be using the database part.

Answer (score 0):

Table Moderators
  id name 
Table Commission
 moderator_id commision_amt commision_status_id

Table Commission_status
status_id name

when you retrieving the commission for moderator

```
 select * from Moderators m join Commision c on m.id = c.moderator_id join Commission_status s on c.commistion_status_id = s.status_id where moderator_id = 1(moderator id)
```

this will give the all commision amounts related to moderator id 
If any confusion free to comment

Second part
summation of all amounts of one staus
sum of all amounts which have specific status like paid and moderator id which logged in

```
select sum(commision_amt ) from Moderators m join Commision c on m.id = c.moderator_id join Commission_status s on c.commistion_status_id = s.status_id where moderator_id = 1(moderator id) and status_id =(status_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir.. But I already know this.. What I want is the logic of addition in array when the user logs in.. Your solution is going to help me for the database part.. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: will you kindly give me example of addition that you want to performed.

Comment: Is this solution helps you or do you have any query

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for, is something like..

```
<?php
// Create an Array to hold our Total values.
$commissionTotals = array();

// loop through each result
// YOU, COULD USE A SWITCH STATEMENT
foreach($commissionArray as $value=>$status)
{
   switch($status)
   {
       case "paid" :
          $commissionTotals['paid'] = $commissionTotals['paid']+$value; 
       break;
       case "Due" :
          $commissionTotals['due'] = $commissionTotals['due']+$value;
       break;
       case "Cancelled" : 
          $commissionTotals['cancelled'] = $commissionTotals['cancelled']+$value;
       break;
   }
}


// OR.. JUST DO A DIRECT LOOKUP
foreach($commissionArray as $value=>$status)
{
   if($status=="paid")
   {
      $commissionTotals['paid'] = $commissionTotals['paid']+$value;
   }
   if($status=="Due")
   {
      $commissionTotals['due'] = $commissionTotals['due']+$value;
   }
   if($status=="Cancelled")
   {
      $commissionTotals['cancelled'] = $commissionTotals['cancelled']+$value;
   }
}
?>
<table>
  <thead>
     <th>
        <td>OrderCode</td>
        <td>PaidAmount</td>
        <td>CancelledAmount</td>
        <td>DueAmount</td>
        <td>Action</td>
     </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $orderCode;?></td>
      <td><?php if(isset($commissionTotals['paid'])) { echo $commissionTotals['paid'];}else{echo 0;}?></td>
      <td><?php if(isset($commissionTotals['due'])) { echo $commissionTotals['due'];}else{echo 0;}?></td>
      <td><?php if(isset($commissionTotals['cancelled'])) { echo $commissionTotals['cancelled'];}else{echo 0;}?></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't you think that your code will get other moderators amount also added up ?

Comment: Im assuming you have some sort of predefined key which should match the user table from the commission table! ie: userID which should be present in both tables!